# JavaFX: I cannot detect null when retrieving value from ChoiceBox

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a simple function that is supposed to loop through all the  text fields, choice boxes, and check boxes in the grid pane. The major problem I'm facing is that when I retrieve a blank value from a choice box I get null, and I'm trying to skip over that value with an statement like **if ( str != null && !str.isEmpty())** . Yet I still get **null** being output to the screen. I'm trying to figure out why it is still being printed to console. **Am I retrieving the value from the choicebox wrong**? Or am I doing the **if statements wrong?**

**Update:** I am putting out the controller code, the fxml code, and the output code. I did not want to show all the code because I know it would be overwhelming for a lot of people. Essentially, I was trying to create a simple application that can create an SQL table structure and output the table structure to a string. There are two buttons on the application, one is to generate another column that will have a text field for the column name, a choice box for the type of value it is , another choicebox that determines if the column is going to be an index or a primary key value, and a check box to determine if the column is going to be auto incremented. The second button is to turn the values into a string.

**CreateTable.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="489.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controllers.CreateTableController">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="216.0" layoutY="20.0" text="Create Table">
         <font>
            <Font size="36.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="157.0" layoutY="90.0" text="Table :">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="tb_name" layoutX="226.0" layoutY="91.0" />
      <ScrollPane layoutX="61.0" layoutY="167.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="479.0">
         <content>
            <GridPane fx:id="fx_grid" hgap="10.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="100.0" prefWidth="477.0" vgap="10.0">
              <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <TextField fx:id="fx_text" />
                  <ChoiceBox fx:id="fx_type" prefWidth="150.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                  <ChoiceBox fx:id="fx_index" prefWidth="150.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
                  <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" />
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </GridPane>
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
      <Button layoutX="275.0" layoutY="420.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onSubmit" text="Create" />
      <Label layoutX="78.0" layoutY="141.0" text="Name" />
      <Label layoutX="183.0" layoutY="141.0" text="Type" />
      <Label layoutX="312.0" layoutY="141.0" text="Index" />
      <Label layoutX="456.0" layoutY="141.0" text="AI" />
      <Button layoutX="363.0" layoutY="420.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#getInfo" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**CreateTableController.java**

```
package controllers;

import models.SQL;
import choices.TableType;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.Set;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;

public class CreateTableController implements Initializable {

    private static List<TableType> typeList = new ArrayList();
    private static List<TableType> indexList = new ArrayList();
    private static int row = 1;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<TableType> fx_type;

    @FXML
    private TextField tb_name;

    @FXML
    private TextField fx_text;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<TableType> fx_index;

    @FXML
    private GridPane fx_grid;

    public void log(String txt) {
        System.out.println(txt);
    }

    private int getInt(Node node) {
        String id = node.getId();
        int start = 1 + id.indexOf("-");
        int end = id.length();
        int value = Integer.valueOf((String) id.subSequence(start, end));

        return value;
    }

    private String compileTableStructure(List<String> text_array , List<String> type_array, List<String> index_array, List<String> auto_array, String indexes){

        String table = "create table if not exists " + tb_name.getText() + " ( \n", text, index = "", type = "",
                auto = "", lastList;

        lastList = getIndexList(indexes);

        for (int x = 0; x < text_array.size(); x++) {

            text = text_array.get(x);
            if (x < type_array.size())
                type = type_array.get(x);
            if (x < index_array.size())
                index = index_array.get(x);
            if (x < auto_array.size())
                auto = auto_array.get(x);

           if(x == text_array.size()-1  && lastList.length() <= 0)
               table += text + " " + type + " " + index + " " + auto ;
           else
               table += text + " " + type + " " + index + " " + auto + ",\n";


            // System.out.println("column:"+x+" "+column);
        }

        if(lastList.length() > 0){

            table += lastList+" \n )";
        }else{

            //table = getIndexList(table);
            table += " \n )";
        }

        return table;
    }


    private String getIndexList(String list) {
        String value = "";
        if (list.length() > 0) {
            int lastNum = list.length() - 1;
            value = (String) list.subSequence(0, lastNum);
        }

        return value;
    }

    @FXML
    void getInfo(ActionEvent event) {

        Set<Node> nodes = fx_grid.lookupAll(".text-field");

        List<String> text_array = new ArrayList();
        List<String> type_array = new ArrayList();
        List<String> index_array = new ArrayList();
        List<String> auto_array = new ArrayList();
        String str = "", indexes = "";

        for (Node node : fx_grid.getChildren()) {
            String s = node.getId();

            if (node instanceof TextField) {
                str = ((TextField) node).getText();
                text_array.add(str);
                // String v =
                // "#text-"+String.valueOf(fx_grid.getRowIndex(node));
                // TextField c = (TextField)fx_grid.lookup(v);
                // System.out.println(c.getText());

            }

            if (node instanceof ChoiceBox && s.contains("type")) {
                str = "" + ((ChoiceBox) node).getValue();
                type_array.add(str);
            }

            if (node instanceof ChoiceBox && s.contains("index")) {
                str = "" + ((ChoiceBox) node).getValue();

                // String rowNum = String.valueOf(fx_grid.getRowIndex(node));
                // System.out.println(fx_grid.getRowIndex(node));
                // rowNum = (rowNum == null)? rowNum:"0";
                // log(str);
                if (str.equals("index")) {
                    String id = "#text-" + getInt(node);
                    TextField txt = (TextField) fx_grid.lookup(id);
                    indexes += "index(" + txt.getText() + "),";

                }else if (str != null && !str.isEmpty()){
                    str = String.valueOf(str);
                    str = str.trim();
                    log(str);
                    if(str == "null")
                        log("this is a null value");

                        index_array.add(str);
                }

                else{
                    index_array.add("not null");
                }



                // log(node.getId());

                // ChoiceBox cc = (ChoiceBox)fx_grid.lookup("#"+node.getId());
                // log(cc.getValue().toString());
            }

            if (node instanceof CheckBox) {
                str = (((CheckBox) node).isSelected() == true) ? "autoincrement" : "";
                auto_array.add(str);
            }
        }


        String table = compileTableStructure(text_array, type_array, index_array, auto_array, indexes);
        log(table);
        //SQL.createTable(table);

    }

    @FXML
    void onSubmit(ActionEvent event) {

        TextField column = new TextField("column-" + row);
        column.setId("text-" + row);

        ChoiceBox typeBox = new ChoiceBox();
        ChoiceBox indexBox = new ChoiceBox();

        typeBox.setId("type-" + row);
        typeBox.setMaxWidth(200);
        indexBox.setId("index-" + row);
        indexBox.setMaxWidth(200);

        typeBox.getItems().addAll(typeList);
        indexBox.getItems().addAll(indexList);

        CheckBox ai = new CheckBox();

        // fx_grid.setHgap(10);

        fx_grid.add(column, 0, row);
        fx_grid.add(typeBox, 1, row);
        fx_grid.add(indexBox, 2, row);
        fx_grid.add(ai, 3, row);
        fx_grid.setHalignment(ai, HPos.CENTER);

        fx_grid.setVgap(10);
        // double height = fx_grid.getHeight()+25;
        // fx_grid.setPrefHeight(height);
        // System.out.println(height);

        row++;

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        typeList.add(new TableType("text"));
        typeList.add(new TableType("numeric"));
        typeList.add(new TableType("blob"));
        typeList.add(new TableType("integer"));
        typeList.add(new TableType("real"));
        typeList.add(new TableType("none"));

        indexList.add(new TableType("index"));
        indexList.add(new TableType("primary key"));

        fx_type.getItems().addAll(typeList);
        fx_index.getItems().addAll(indexList);

        fx_type.setId("type-0");
        fx_index.setId("index-0");
        fx_text.setId("text-0");

    }

}
```

**Output**

```
create table if not exists  ( 
column text primary key ,
column-1 text null ,
column-2 numeric null ,
index(column-2) 
 )
```

Comment: I don't see the output statement. Please let others see what you are printing.

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: `if (str.equals("index"))` throws a NPE iff `str` is `null`. A check that is executed later does not change this. Furthermore concatenating anything to a string results in a non-null value. This check `str != null` never yields `false`. BTW: Please improve the description of the behaviour. There is no statement producing any output in your code (neither to the console nor to some `Node`). If it's an exception that occurs please post the complete stacktrace and mark any lines in your code.

Comment: Well  to everybody asking for the output, I can put it out, but there will be a lot more code to look through if you want to see the final version. That is the reason why I tried to have a bite size version of my code, so you can see the area  that is giving me the only problem

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: you certainly did read the reference to the help page given above, didn't you :) Then why don't you comply? The idea is that you provide the smallest possible example - complete standalone compilable runnable - that demonstrates the problem. Certainly not your production code but something you wrote just for demonstrating the error, that's something you have to do anyway and always when tracking down misbehaviour of code ... often you even find the error yourself in the process of doing it. And if not, developers here can simply through it into their favorite IDE and see for themselves ..

Comment: "*I did not want to show all the code because I know it would be overwhelming for a lot of people.*" Which is why the link I gave you talks about **Minimal** Complete, and Verifiable **example**.

Comment: @user1803551 That is why I originally  had a little snippet of it, but people in the comments asked to post the "complete stacktrace". So I posted it

Comment: A stack trace are the printed lines in the error stream given for an exception - where it originated, why and the path it took, it's not lines of code. 2 out of the 4 people in the comments asked for an MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
str = "" + ((ChoiceBox) node).getValue();
```

resolves to the following result in str

```
"" + "null"
```

This is neither str == null nor str.isEmpty.
You will get the correct result when you replace the above line with:

```
Result r = ((ChoiceBox) node).getValue();
if(r != null)
    str = r;
else str = null;
```

Of course you will have to replace `Result` with whatever is in your ChoiceBox. If it is a also a String you could also write:

```
str = ((ChoiceBox) node).getValue();
```